# amcl dont do the localization job and results in unmatching maps

Tags: navigation, sicklms, costmap, amcl, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

I'm using lms100 only, when i use gmapping+laser scan matcher and costmap at the same time it was ok, but then i tried the other option; static map(which i built via gmapping before), map_server and amcl (again with laser scan matcher for odometry) can't manage it. it looks like amcl didn't do its job.

i don't have a robot system so i don't know which amcl (diff or omni) should i choose or if that even affects the functionality of amcl.

in rviz, it looks like this.

[image: image description]

my launch file:

```
 <launch>
      <param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>
      <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" 
        args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /laser 40" />
    
      <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
        args="-d $(find laser_scan_matcher)/demo.rviz"/>
    
     <node pkg="lms1xx" name="lms1xx" type="LMS1xx_node">
        <param name="host" value="169.254.10.200" />
     </node>
    
      <node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" 
        name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">
        <param name="fixed_frame" value = "odom"/>
        <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>
        <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
      </node>
    
       <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find bsk)/launch/maps/gcost2.yaml"/>
    
      <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen" >
      <!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->
      <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
      <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.1"/>
      <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.2" />
      <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
      <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>
      <param name="min_particles" value="500"/>
      <param name="max_particles" value="5000"/>
      <param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>
      <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
      <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>
      <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
    
      <!-- translation std dev, m -->
      <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.2"/>
      <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.2"/>
      <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.5"/>
      <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.05"/>
      <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.05"/>
      <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.5"/>
      <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>
      <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
      <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
      <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
      <!-- <param name="laser_model_type" value="beam"/> -->
      <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
      <param name="update_min_d" value="0.2"/>
      <param name="update_min_a" value="0.5"/>
      <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/>
      <param name="base_frame_id" type="str" value="base_link" />
      <param name="global_frame_id" type="str" value="map" />
      <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
      <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.1"/>
      <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.0"/>
      <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.0"/>
      <param name="use_map_topic" value="true" />
      <param name="first_map_only" value="true" />
    </node>
    
     <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
        <rosparam file="$(find bsk)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find bsk)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find bsk)/launch/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="$(find bsk)/launch/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="$(find bsk)/launch/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
        </node>
        </launch>
```

costmap_common_params.yaml:

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[-0.325, -0.325], [-0.325, 0.325], [0.325, 0.325], [0.46, 0.0], [0.325, -0.325]]
#robot_radius: 0.46
inflation_radius: 0.3

observation_sources: base_scan
base_scan: {data_type: LaserScan,  sensor_frame: /laser,  topic: /scan, expected_update_rate: 0.4,
  observation_persistence: 0.0, marking: true, clearing: true, max_obstacle_height: 0.4, min_obstacle_height: 0}
```

local_costmap_params.yaml:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 1.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.020000
```

global_costmap_params.yaml:

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 1.0
  static_map: true
```

base_local_planner_params.yaml: (didnt modify anything because i dont have robot system)

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.45
  min_vel_x: 0.1
  max_vel_theta: 1.0
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.4

  acc_lim_theta: 3.2
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5

  holonomic_robot: true
```

the errors in the terminal:

```
   [WARN] [1467201369.564382684]: Trajectory Rollout planner initialized with param meter_scoring not set. Set it to true to make your settins robust against changes of costmap resolution.
    [ WARN] [1467201370.169816275]: The /scan observation buffer has not been updated for 2.27 seconds, and it should b updated every 0.40 seconds.
    [ WARN] [1467201370.301085119]: The /scan observation buffer has not been updated for 1.25 seconds, and it should be updated every 0.40 seconds.
        [ INFO] [1467201370.739975409]: Recovery behavior will clear layer obstacles
        [ INFO] [1467201370.987085606]: Recovery behavior will clear layer obstacles
        [ INFO] [1467201641.943586259]: Setting pose (1467201641.943557): -2.015 0.022 -0.000
    [ INFO] [1467201669.857466951]: Setting pose (1467201669.857429): -1.915 0.013 -1.619
    [ INFO] [1467201685.386250862]: Setting pose (1467201685.386178): -2.534 0.053 2.826
    [ WARN] [1467201716.436344460]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1467201716.4363, global_pose stamp: 1467201716.0885, tolerance: 0.3000
    [ WARN] [1467201716.437433328]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238393/amcl-dont-do-the-localization-job-and-results-in-unmatching-maps/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you should clean up your costmap''s yaml file of these warning, and then test amcl.
the warning shows that you didn't config yaml file well.

---

Originally posted by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) with karma: 255 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-06-30**:
but that `/scan observation buffer has not been updated` error was just pop up twice.I saw answer from David Lu said if that warning shows up just in beginning its ok and other warnings happened because i tried 2DPoseEstimate in rviz which didnt work cuz amcl i think. I updated question with yamls

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2016-06-30**:
I mean Trajectory Rollout planner is in planner yaml. modify it first.

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2016-06-30**:
and in laser_scan_matcher, `<param name="fixed_frame" value = "odom"/>`
i don't think above is right. you can also change or remove: expected_update_rate: 0.4,

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-06-30**:
i removed expected rate and that warning is gone. main problem is still exist. why do you think odom isnt right? this configuration is ok with gmapping&costmap so i didnt change it.

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-06-30**:
i updated question with base_local_planner_params.yaml but since i dont have a robot, didnt modify just use the defaults. I dont need to use planner after move_base, just want to manage to see local and global costmaps succesfully with a given static map